# HTML Requests in Android

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-asynctask, httprequest

so here is my issue: I am working on a mobile App, that requires a login. I am programming in Android Studio / Java. Got a quite good experience in Java but i've never done networking.. There is a .asp script on a server that processes the login, which i need to send the login data to.   The best way to solve this i think is a HTTP - Request, because if you enter the url of the script into the browser, followed by the query string containing the login data, you already get a response.

```
http://sampleurl.info/actions/checklogin.asp?userName=klingenhaeger&password=droid&device=android
```

returns a Json String containing a profile token and a timestamp and the profile name.Like:

```
{"profil_token":"qn2hJcRQixYjG7yyW956g1407921902","profil_name":"Marc KlingenhÃ¤ger","timestamp":"1407921902"}
```

This profile token is then attached to every url the user requests, and in that way the user gains permission to all the websites.
I read that you can do the same thing with a http GET request, but me and my coworker worked on this 
(such a simple thing) for nine ours and didn't get our code working...
We tried out heaps of snippets, this is our most simple attempt:
In the Main activity, on clicking the button that leads to the login, LoginActivity.class is called using a Intent.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
```

After entering the user data, the user clicks the login button, and the method attemptLogin(); gets called.

```
public void attemptLogin() {
    if (mAuthTask != null) {
        return;
    }

    // Reset errors.
    mEmailView.setError(null);
    mPasswordView.setError(null);

    // Store values at the time of the login attempt.
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    boolean cancel = false;
    View focusView = null;


    // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
        mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
        focusView = mPasswordView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    // Check for a valid email address.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
        mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
        focusView = mEmailView;
        cancel = true;
    }

    if (cancel) {
        // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
        // form field with an error.
        focusView.requestFocus();
    } else {
        // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
        // perform the user login attempt.
        showProgress(true);
        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
    }
}
```

So after some error detection, the class userLoginTask (subclass of AsyncTask) is initialized to handle the networking stuff, because initializing the http request in the main thread seems to cause an exception. We  didn't manage to code a HTTP - Request here so far.. (thats the main problem)

public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    private final String mEmail;
    private final String mPassword;

    UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
        mEmail = email;
        mPassword = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

        try {
            // Simulate network access.
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return false;
        }

        for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
            String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
            if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
            }
        }

        // TODO: register the new account here.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);

        if (success) {
            finish();
        } else {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
            mPasswordView.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        mAuthTask = null;
        showProgress(false);
    }
}
```

So my question is basically, how can i initialize a HTTP - Request in the UserLoginTask class. Any Ideas? Thanks in advance! :)

Falco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a URL object and open a stream to your HTTP server.
The server response can be read through this stream:

```
String url = "http://sampleurl.info/actions/checklogin.asp?userName=klingenhaeger&password=droid&device=android";
try {
    URL u = new URL(url);
    InputStream is = u.openStream(); // Opens streaming connection to url
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(); // Buffer to store saved data
    String input = null;

    while((input = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        // Read data until the end of the stream
        result.append(input);
    }

    // Do something with result here
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When you have retrieved the data as a string, you can parse the JSON to get the `profile_token`

Comment: Cool, so i tried they by writing a method getJsonString() that executes your code. On calling this method though i get a Exeption because the networking is executed in the main thread. I can not call the method i wrote in the UserLoginTask, which is the separate thread. Does somebody know how to fix that?

Comment: Hmm, you have to put the code in the doInBackground method. You can then let onPostExecute take a string as an argument, which is the downloaded JSON string (which you return from doInBackground) :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Android's Volley http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html and issue an HTTP POST request, sending username / password.
I advise hashing the password (MD5 or something else - depends on what the back-end handles to decrypt).

Answer (score 0):

Google suggests using [`HttpUrlConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).

An example that should do what you want is very simple, especially when using GET. First, construct an URL from String. Your response is InputStream, which you parse to JSONObject and obtain your token.

```
URL url = new URL("http://sampleurl.info/actions/checklogin.asp?userName=klingenhaeger&password=droid&device=android");
//later:
URL url = new URL("http://sampleurl.info/actions/checklogin.asp?token=abcde");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);
finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
}
```

This is recommended approach, since it does not require any external libraries, and it can easily be converted to use POST instead of GET and HTTPS instead of HTTP.